# How to open an image with standart iOS gallery by clicking on it?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, deeplink

I have a js script on my web-page. It looks like this:

```
<script>
function openimg() {
    window.open("photos-redirect://")
}
</script>
```

And I have an image:

```
<img src="some_photo.jpg" onclick="openimg()">
```

When I click on image, it launches standard iOS gallery, but there is no image I need. Is there any way to open image by native application?

Comment: Hello!  are you asking how to save an image (`some_photo.jpg`) from the web into the camera roll or photo library on the iPhone?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann please tell if you know how to do it